# How to disable dropDown after selection in autocompleteTextView

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I'm on an android project since September, and I've to deal with AutocompleteTextView.
I made my personnal ArrayAdapter to populate the dropdown suggestion list, it works, but act strangely.

When i select an item in the dropdown list, it replace the text in my textView by the selection (that's okay), but after this, reShow the Dropdown.
I want it to hide until the user type something else on the keyboard.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
private List<String> autocompleteAddress;

addressBox = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.form_address_box);

autocompleteAdapterAddress = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, autocompleteAddress){

  @Override
  public Filter getFilter(){

    Filter custom_filter = new Filter(){

      @Override
      protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint){

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = autocompleteAddress;
        filterResults.count = autocompleteAddress.size();

        return filterResults;
      }

      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    };

    return custom_filter;
  }
};

addressBox.setAdapter(autocompleteAdapterAddress);

addressBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

    //ac is an asynctask populating the suggestion list (autocompleteAddress)

    GetGoogleAutocompletion ac = new GetGoogleAutocompletion();
    ac.execute(addressBox.getText().toString());
  }

  @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
  @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
});

addressBox.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // here i just store the autocompleted text in a String
  }
});
```

I thought the setText() method would be call in onItemClick(), and I could have used dismissDropDown(), but as i overrided onItemClick(), I'm pretty sure it's not there.

So i really don't know neither where the setText() is called, nor how to avoid the display of the dropDown menu after a selection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find out what to do here?